# How to smooth ROC curve?

Tags: python, classification, roc, auc

I draw the ROC curve for different classifiers with the following code, but in all plots (from different classifiers), the diagrams are triangular like the example below. How can I have a smoother plot?

```
def plot_roc_curve(fpr, tpr, classifier):
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='orange', label='ROC')
    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='darkblue', linestyle='--')
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.title(str(classifier) + 'Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) Curve ')
    plt.legend(loc="lower right")
    plt.show()

from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_predicted)
plot_roc_curve(fpr, tpr, key)
```

**What I get:**
[image: ROC curve]

**What I want:**
[image: ROC curve]

The dataset: https://www.file.io/download/Aq7LT88NBVSh

```
y_test 
36     1
988    0
416    1
300    1
860    0
      ..
780    0
130    1
316    1
577    0
694    0

y_predict
[1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
 1 1 1]
```

Comment: The shape of the ROC-curve depends on the contents of `y_test, y_predicted` and we don't know where that comes from.

Comment: So how can I mark the points like the expected diagram?

Comment: For the data you fed to it, that's the curve. Again, you didn't show what `y_test, y_predicted` contains. I can only guess that the number of samples is very low.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've added the dataset in the edit.

Comment: `y_predicted` needs to be non-thresholded i.e. you should feed the raw confidence values `0.0...1.0` to it. Otherwise a ROC-curve (which visualizes the behaviour at different confidence thresholds) makes no sense.

Comment: I'm afraid, I'm a beginner. Could you please show me how to edit the code for that?

Comment: If you don't have the original, non-thresholded values for y_predict, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 4):

You're using thresholded predictions to generate the ROC-curve. You should instead use the original confidence values, otherwise you will get only 1 intermediary point on the curve.

Here is some example data and the ROC-curves you would get.

```
y_test: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
y_predicted: [1, 0.405, 0.601, 0.579, 0.03, 0.98, 0.06, 0.242, 0.379, 0.09, ...
y_predicted_thresholded: [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
```

[image]